# Can I shorten this bubble sort without creating a new list?

Tags: python

I have made a bubble sort algorithm but I was wondering if there was any way of shortening it without creating a new list. This is what a have managed to get so far:

```
for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
    for i in range(passnum):
        if alist[i] > alist[i+1]:
            temp = alist[i]
            alist[i] = alist[i+1]
            alist[i+1] = temp
print(alist)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a temporary variable, there is a direct way to exchange the value of two variables in Python.

```
for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
    for i in range(passnum):
        if alist[i] > alist[i+1]: 
            alist[i],alist[i+1] = alist[i+1],alist[i] 
print(alist)
```